# Measurable Functions as Limits (a.e) of Step Functions

Tags: measure-theory

I saw the following theorem and its proof.

**Theorem 1:** Given a measurable function $f$ on $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of [simple functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) $\{f_k\}$ which converges point-wise to $f$ **everywhere**.

I want to see the proof of the following theorem, following Stein-Shakarchi.

**Theorem 2:** Given a measurable function $f$ on $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of [step functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) $\{f_k\}$ which converges point-wise to $f$ **almost everywhere**.

The proof given by Stein-Shakarchi starts with- *it is sufficient to show that any simple function is limit almost everywhere of a sequence of step functions*.

I don't understand the italic statement. Can you help me? Also, is there simple proof of Theorem 2, which do not refers to Theorem 1?

Comment: Not a full answer, but the italics part means that if we show that any given simple function can be approximated by other simple functions a.e. then we're done. This follows because we can construct a sequence of simple functions that converges pointwise everywhere to any $f$. I.e. let $f$ be measurable and $s_n \to f$ pointwise everywhere. If we can find a sequence $s_{n_k} \to s_n$ a.e. pointwise then we can combine these sequences to create a sequence that converges a.e. pointwise to $f$.

Comment: @DanZimm: The argument sounds convincing, but I am not completely sure. One of the problems with a.e. convergence is that it is not given by a topology (and thus also not by a metric), so that arguments of the kind you mention are **not** automatic in general.

Comment: Presumably this is using the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @PhoemueX this is fair - iirc this is the gist of the proof though, no? (Of course there's quite a bit of details missing, hence why I commented instead of answered)

Comment: Little strange, but exactly in that page is proof and answer which you asking about.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple proof that is tediously long. As with many proofs dealing
with measure, it proceeds by showing an equivalent result for indicator
functions, then simple functions and then measurable function.

I think the essence of the result is 1), the rest is generalisation.

I am assuming that you are using the Lebesgue measure $m$.

Since we can extend $f$ by letting $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin E$, there is no loss of generality in taking $E= \mathbb{R}$.

1) If $A$ has finite measure and $\epsilon>0$, we can find a finite collection of disjoint open intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ such that $m (A \triangle \cup_{k \le n} I_k) \le \epsilon$.

Suppose $A$ is measurable set of finite measure. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a (possibly countable) collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}$ such that $A \subset \cup_k I_k$ and  $mA \le \sum_k m I_k \le mA+ {\epsilon \over 2}$. Since $m (\cup_k I_k) = m A + m (\cup_k I_k \setminus A)$, we have
$m ( \cup_{k \le n} I_k \setminus A) \le  m ( \cup_{k} I_k \setminus A) \le { \epsilon \over 2}$, for any $n$.
We also have $mA = m (A \cap \cup_{k \le n} I_k ) + m ( A \setminus \cup_{k \le n} I_k)$, hence by continuity of measure, we can find some $n$ such that
$m ( A \setminus \cup_{k \le n} I_k) \le { \epsilon \over 2}$. Hence for some $N$ we have $m (A \triangle \cup_{k \le n} I_k) \le \epsilon$.

To obtain  disjoint intervals, suppose two of the open intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ overlap, say  $I_{k_1}$ and $I_{k_2}$. Then $I_{k_1} \cup I_{k_2}$ is also an open interval that contains both intervals and
$m (I_{k_1} \cup I_{k_2}) \le m I_{k_1} + m I_{k_2}$. So, we remove 
$I_{k_1}$, $I_{k_2}$ from the collection and replace them by the combined
interval $I_{k_1} \cup I_{k_2}$. We continue until there are no overlapping intervals. Let $\{ I_k' \}_{k=1}^{n'}$ be the resulting collection of disjoint intervals. Since $\cup_{k=1}^n I_k = \cup_{k=1}^{n'} I_k'$, all of the above estimates are still valid and we have 
$m (A \triangle \cup_{k \le n'} I_k') \le \epsilon$.

2) If $B = I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_n$ where the $I_k$ are disjoint intervals, then $1_{B} = \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{I_k}$ is a step function.

3) Let $A$ have finite measure and $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a step function $s$  and a set $\Delta$ such that $1_A(x) = s(x)$ for $x \notin \Delta$ and $m \Delta \le \epsilon$. Furthermore, if $A \subset J$, where $J$ is an bounded interval, we can take $\Delta \subset J$ as well (in particular, we have
$s(x) = 0$ for $x \notin J$).

From 1), we have disjoint open intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ such that
$m (A \triangle \cup_{k \le n} I_k) \le \epsilon$. Let $s=\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{I_k}$ and $\Delta = A \triangle \cup_{k \le n} I_k$.
Then we see that $m \Delta \le \epsilon$ and
if $x \notin \Delta$, we have $s(x) = 1_A(x)$.

If $A \subset J$, a bounded interval, let $s'=s \cdot 1_J$, and note that $s'$
is a step function. Notice that if $x \notin J$, then $s'(x) = 0 = 1_A(x)$ and so we have $s'(x) = 1_A(x)$ for $x \notin \Delta' = \Delta \cap J$, with $m \Delta' \le m \Delta \le \epsilon$.

4) If $A$ is measurable and $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a step function $s$  and a set $\Delta$ such that $1_A(x) = s(x)$ for $x \notin \Delta$ and $m \Delta \le \epsilon$.

(Note that the finite sum of step functions is a step function.)

Let $B_n = A \cap [n,n+1)$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $s_n$ and $\Delta_n \subset [n,n+1)$ be the step function and set such that $1_{B_n}(x) = s_n(x)$ for all $x \notin \Delta_n$ with $m \Delta_n \le {1 \over 2^{|n|+2}} \epsilon$. (Note that we can take $J=[n,n+1)$, so that $\Delta_n \subset [n,n+1)$. Consequently, $s_n(x) = 0$ when $x \notin [n,n+1)$.)
Let $s = \sum_n s_n$ and $\Delta = \cup_n \Delta_n$. Then if $x \notin \Delta$, we have $s(x) = \sum_n s_n(x) = \sum_n 1_{B_n}(x) = 1_{B_{\lfloor x \rfloor}} (x) = 1_A(x)$ and $m \Delta \le { 3 \over 4} \epsilon$.

5) If $\sigma$ is a real valued simple function and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a step function $s$ and a set $\Delta$ such that $m \Delta \le \epsilon$ and
$\sigma(x) = s(x) $ for $x \notin \Delta$.

Suppose $\sigma = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$, where the $A_k$ are measurable. Using 4), choose $s_k, \Delta_k$ such that $1_{A_k}(x) = s_k(x)$ for $x \notin \Delta_k$, and $m \Delta_k \le {1 \over n} \epsilon$. If we let
$s = \sum_k \alpha_k s_k$ (note that $s$ is a step function)
 and $\Delta = \cup_k \Delta_k$, we have $m \Delta \le \epsilon$ and if
$x \notin \Delta$, then $\sigma(x) = s(x)$.

And finally:

6) If $f$ is measurable, there are step functions $s_n$ such that $s_n(x) \to f(x)$ for ae. $x$.

There are real valued simple functions $\sigma_n$ such that $\sigma_n(x) \to f(x) $ for all $x$. Using 5), choose step functions $s_n$ and sets $\Delta_n$
such that $s_n(x) = \sigma_n(x)$ for $x \notin \Delta_n$, and 
$m \Delta_n \le {1 \over n} {1 \over 2^{n+1}}$.

Note that if $s_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$, then we must have $s_n(x) \neq \sigma_n(x)$ for infinitely many $n$. This means $x \in \Delta_n$ infinitely often. Equivalently, we have
$x \in Q=\cap_n \cup_{k \ge n} \Delta_k$.
Since $m Q \le m (\cup_{k \ge n} \Delta_k)
\le \sum_{k \ge n} {1 \over k 2^{k+1}} \le  {1 \over n}$ for all $n$, we see that $m Q = 0$.
Consequently, for any $x \notin Q$, there is some $N$ such that
$s_n(x) = \sigma_n(x)$ for all $n \ge N$, and so
$s_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Comment: In the proof of (3), some of the intervals $I_k$ could be infinite, isn't it? So, in the definition of step function, you are allowing an interval to be infinite also, where function could take non-zero value.

Comment: No, all the intervals (with non-zero multiplier) have finite measure. If an  interval had infinite measure then the set $\Delta$ would have to have infinite measure since $A$ has finite measure.

Comment: For example, $A=\mathbb{Q}$. How will we proceed Step 3?

Comment: Take $s(x) = 0$ and $\Delta = \mathbb{Q}$. Then $m \Delta = 0$ and $s(x) = 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ for all $x \notin \Delta$.

Comment: ! OK! Fine. I will see back the complete proof.

Comment: Remember that even in Part 1) above, the collection of intervals need not be a cover of $A$.

Comment: OK! This was a point I not looked carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18212/discussion-between-groups-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 0):

Some notes for myself:

Let $H=(0,1]^d$ and use the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. Let ${\cal H_n} = \{ {1 \over 2^n} (H+\{x\}) | x \in \mathbb{Z}^d)$.
Note that ${\cal H_n}$ forms a partition of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
For $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let $p_n(x) = {1 \over 2^n} \lfloor 2^n x \rfloor $ (with the floor taken for each component separately) and note that $\|x-p_n(x)\| < {1 \over 2^n}$, that is, $x \in B(p_n(x),{1 \over 2^n})$.
Also, note that $B(p_n(x),{1 \over 2^n}) \subset B(x,{2 \over 2^n})$.

Suppose $V$ is open and bounded. Define $V_n = \cup \{ A \in {\cal H_n} | A \subset V \}$. Note that $V_n \subset V$ and, more relevant, $V_n$ is expressible as a step function as it can be written as the sum of indicators of a finite number of elements of
${\cal H_n}$.

Furthermore, note that $\cup_n V_n = V$ and hence $m(V \setminus V_n) \to 0$.

Suppose $E$ is measurable with finite measure. Let $E_M = E \cap B(0,M)$ and note that
$m(E \setminus E_M) \to 0$. The $E_M$ are measurable, bounded and have finite measure.

By the definition of the Lebesgue measure, for any set $B$ of finite measure, there
is a sequence of open sets $W_k$ containing $B$ such that $m(W_k \setminus B) \to 0$.

Finally, suppose $E$ has finite measure (and hence measurable) and $\epsilon>0$. Then
for some $M$ we have a measurable bounded $E_M$ such that $m(E\setminus E_M) < {1 \over 3} \epsilon$. Now pick an open $W_k$ containing $E_M$ such that $m(W_k\setminus E_M) < {1 \over 3} \epsilon$. Finally, pick a $V_n$ contained in $W_k$ such that 
$m(W_k\setminus V_n) < {1 \over 3} \epsilon$.

Note that $1_{E}-1_{V_n} = 1_E-1_{E_M}+1_{E_M}-1_{W_k}+1_{W_k}-1_{V_n}$, and
$m(A \triangle B) = \int |1_A-1_B | dm$, so we have
$\int | 1_{E}-1_{V_n} | dm \le  \int |1_E-1_{E_M} |dm + \int |1_{E_M}-1_{W_k} |dm + \int |1_{W_k}-1_{V_n} |dm <  {1 \over 3} \epsilon + {1 \over 3} \epsilon + {1 \over 3} \epsilon = \epsilon$.

Comment: How does this post relate to the question and your other post? Is it still needed?