# Transitivity of pointwise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to know if the following statement is true or not:

Here we consider functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
We are given a function $f$, families of functions $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ with the following properties:

(1) There is a sequence of functions $\{ \varphi_k \}$ in $\mathcal{F}$ pointwise convergent to $f$.

(2) For each function $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}$, there is a sequence of functions $\{ \psi_l \}$ in $\mathcal{G}$ that converges pointwise to $\varphi$ almost everywhere.

Then we can find a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{G}$ that converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere.

In particular, if $f$ is any measurable function, $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) and $\mathcal{G}$ is the set of all [step functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) then this is true.

I believe it is generally false but I couldn't come up with a counter example.

Initially, my question was the same as [Measurable Functions as Limits (a.e) of Step Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992900/measurable-functions-as-limits-a-e-of-step-functions), which deals with the special case I described. I read both the proof in the book by Stein-Shakarchi and the answer of the question, but they rely on something stronger:

(3) For each function $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\psi \in \mathcal{G}$ which agrees with $\varphi$ except for a set $E$ with $m(E) < \epsilon$.

Edit: I'm asking this question because the book starts the proof by saying:

*it suffices to show that every simple functions can be approximated by step functions*

and concludes:

*we've found a sequence of step functions that converges pointwise to given simple function almost everywhere.*

This seems to me, is using the general statement I wrote above even though we had a stronger condition (3) in the middle of the proof.

Comment: Take a [Baire class 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function) function that is not Baire class 1?

Comment: @DavidMitra It seems this is exactly what I was wondering! Thanks!